# Creating a default constructor on a subclass

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I'm still learning C# and just had a basic question about inheritance.

Lets say I have an abstract class `SportsPlayer`:

```
public abstract class SportsPlayer
{

    string name;    /*1ai*/
    int age;        /*1aii*/
    Sexs gender;    /*1aiii*/ 

    //1b
    public SportsPlayer(string n, int a, Sexs g)
    {
        this.name = n;
        this.age = a;
        this.gender = g;
    }
}
```

And a subclass called `SoccerPlayer`:

```
public class SoccerPlayer : SportsPlayer
    {
        Positions position;
        public SoccerPlayer(string n, int a, Sexs g, Positions p)
            : base(n, a, g)
        {
            this.position = p;
        }

        //Default constructor
        public SoccerPlayer()
        {

        }
```

Is it possible to create a constructor on the subclass which is passed no arguments or am I right in thinking that in order to create a default constructor on a subclass, the super class must have a default constructor too?

---

Also, if I were to add a default constructor to the super class, how would I initialize the super class variables in the subclass constructor? In java its `super()`, in C# it's??

```
public SoccerPlayer():base()
{
    base.name = "";
}
```

???

Comment: You mean like the constructor commented `//Default constructor`? No reason you can't do that, although you'd do well to use `: base(...)` with some default values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a parameterless constructor on the derived class, but it still needs to pass arguments to the base class constructor:

```
    //Default constructor
    public SoccerPlayer()
        : base("default name", 0, default(Sexs))
    {

    }
```

Or you could add a default constructor to the base class...

Answer (score 5):

you can have a parameter less constructor in child class but you need to invoke the parameterized constructor of base or same class like so

```
public Child():base(1,2,3)
{
}
```

or

```
public Child(): this(1,2,3)
{
}
```

In your case it wouldn't make much sense though. A soccer player can't have a default name or age.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your new constructor, but if you don't call `base(...)` something on base class couldn't be initialized.
So you should use:

```
public SoccerPlayer()
    :base("name", 30, Sexs.???)
{
}
```